# how to pass arguments to GET method in RESTfull webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest

I have to pass `UserName` and `password` as arguments into `GET` method for validation.after processing I need to get response.so how can I pass value into `RESTful` webservice `GET` method?

Answer (score 2):

To pass parameters in HTTP GET you should use a `?` delimiter. Such as

```
https://mywebsite.com/user/login?username=bob&password=123
https://mywebsite.com/user/login?paramname1=value1&paramname2=value2
```

Make sure to always use `https` with any sensitive data. You may also need to escape/encode both username and password to allow extended ASCII. If you need to support UNICODE you should consider using a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use POST method if you want to do something with user name and password. because when you use GET method, the password would be visible on the URI,

```
https://samplesite.com/page/login?username=John&password=123
https://sampleste.com/page/login?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Instead, you could use POST method to send user name and password values and in that case the URI would like below

```
https://samplesite.com/page/login
```

And the values will be sent as,

```
POST /page/login.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: samplesite.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

And you get below advantages on POST Method for secured transaction with server.

- It never cached
- Requests will remain in the browser history
- Requests cannot be bookmarked
- Requests have no restrictions on data length

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for Login validation,

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            String downloadedString= null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            //for registerhttps://te
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("YOUR LOGIN URL");
            //add data
            try{
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", UserName_Edit.getText().toString()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", userPassword_Edit.getText().toString()));

                //add data
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in),1024);
                String line;
                while((line = bfrd.readLine()) != null)
                    stringbuilder.append(line);

                downloadedString = stringbuilder.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("downloadedString:in login:::"+downloadedString);
```

Use `AsyncTask` for your authentication and write the above method in the `doInBackground()`.

**EDIT**

You can follow below tutorials also,

http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the OQ was for a GET not a POST.

Comment: @Ne0: I know my friend.But I guess `POST` is the best way to send data as an argument.

Comment: #Spring Breaker   thanks for your anser brother.i also used asynTask class.and i set values.but i need server side.can u show?

Comment: @user3543997: What do you mean by server side?

Comment: #Spring Breaker if i use POST,then can i get Response?

Comment: #Spring Breaker: in POST we cannot return any values.right?  but i want return value

Comment: @user3543997: Well it depends how your server side code is written to respond this request.And yeah `POST` also returns response values.

Comment: #Spring Breaker: i need to pass arguments and also that method returns some values.in `Get`,we can return value.but we cannot pass arguments. in `POST`, we can pass arguments.but we cannot return any value.but i want both(Argument passing and return some values) within one method

Comment: @user3543997: It is possible my friend. see this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: @Spring Breaker:how can i returns response value from Post?

Comment: @user3543997: Well if you are asking server side code, I afraid I have less knowledge on that.

Comment: @Spring Breaker: oh ok ok friend.but can you clarify me how can i returns response value from POST?

Comment: @user3543997:Sorry my friend, it's not possible to explain it here and it seems like you don't have enough reputation to enter a chat room too.Refer the tutorials that I have mentioned, it may help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can pass arguments to GET method in RESTfull like :

```
 http://yoururl/<arg1>/<arg2>
```

eg.

```
 http://yoururl/abc/123
```